# iphone app background NSTimer (Poll data at regular interval)

Tags: iphone, background, nstimer

I need to get data in background from server at regular interval,
Nstimer seems don't work in background.

Do i need to edit the plist for Void or audio to make NStimer work in background ?
 Would any one explain the process we sample code.

Regards,
Avinash

Comment: "Nstimer seems don't work in background." Code?

Comment: I think he's trying to say that when his app is backgrounded, his code doesn't run because the app is suspended.

Comment: Yes in suspended mode, so that i keep on polling data from server

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: toTarget: withObject:]
```

Example usage:

```
 -(void) pollBackground
 {
     @autoreleasepool {

          // every five seconds, update list
          NSTimeInterval interval = 5; 

          while (poll)
          {
              // update from server

              [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:interval];
          } 

     }
 }

 -(void) viewDidLoad {
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(pollBackground) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 }
```

This should keep running in the background.

Comment: I need to access data when app is in background mode,that is when user clicks 'Home button'